# Can't link my UITableViewController to my nested UITableView

Tags: uitableview, nested, view, segue

I need to provide some background to explain how I got to where I am. I'm trying to create an interaction that involves different segues (slide up from the bottom, slide in from right) and, as far as I can tell I can't mix these two styles amongst scenes that are embedded in a Navigation Controller because the Show segue will only appear from right to left if I do.

The behavior I want is: Initial View Controller -> Settings (segue from bottom) ->  -> detail for selected Setting ('standard' segue from right to left)

I also want to put a navigation bar in the Settings view so I can have a Done button that will close the view (slide out of sight from top to bottom) like this:

[image]

Interface builder won't let me add a navigation bar when I'm using a Navigation Controller and without one it looks like this:

[image]

So, I tried something from a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582824/ios-tableviewcontroller-scrolling-away-content-and-navigation-bar-under-status-b) that suggested nesting views. It almost works (the first screenshot above was taken from that code), but it resulted in a new problem. That problem is that I can't link the nested `UITableViewController' to my SettingsTableViewController.swift custom class. It's simply not an option in the dropdown list of classes and so I can't configure my table of Settings options.

Here's the hierarchy I now have based on the suggestion from that thread:

[image]

Also, I've confirmed that my `SettingsTableViewController.swift` is subclassing `UITableViewController`.

I'm stumped and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: .... that's because your green arrow is pointing to a `UITableView`, not a `UITableViewController`.  But I think you are heading up a blind alley.  I think you can achieve what you want by embedding your Settings view controller in a `UINavigationController`, then using a "Present Modally" segue to present the `UINavigationController` (which will give the slide up from bottom effect).  Then use a 'show' segue from the Settings view controller (which will give the slide in from right effect).

Comment: Oh, that is kind of a silly mistake. I'm so used to working with a `UITableViewController` that I was trying to use one our of habit. I originally started down that path that you suggested - using Present Modally - but that results in the problem you see in the second screenshot above where the first cell is too high. I need a Navigation Bar between the Status Bar and the first cell (like the first screenshot) but IB won't let me when I have the whole thing embedded in a Navigation Controller.

Comment: In IB, uncheck "Extend edges: Under top bars" in the attributes inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this,

1. Add a UIViewController and a UINavigationController(this automatically comes with a UITableViewController.
2. For example sake, add a button to the UIViewController, right click and drag to the UINavigationController and setup the segue to the following show in the image.[image: Segue]
3. Add another UIViewController and right click drag from the UITableViewController to the new UIViewController and use a push segue, which you can reference when you do 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'.

You shouldn't need to connect things, because your UITableViewController is the rootViewController of a UINavigationController. If you use a UITableViewController the only thing you should have in it's hierarchy is the UITableView, if you want other things, you need to use a UIViewController and add a UITableView, but I don't think you need this because you can achieve your requirements with the default options.

Comment if this does not make sense, good luck,

Comment: Also to add your 'Done' button to the navigation bar of the tableview, UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneMethod:)]; self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton; Sorry if this code is not readable, I can edit my answer if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I have almost everything working except for the Done button. I couldn't get your 'Done' button code to work but I'm able to get it to appear using this: `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)`. I just to figure out exactly how to set the `action` properly so it will unwind the segue and dismiss the modal Settings view.

Comment: No worries, the code I sent you was in objective-c, I think for swift your action parameter looks like this, `action: #selector(yourDismissMethod)`, then in 'yourDismissMethod' you can use `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` to dismiss the modal.

Comment: I got it all to work. Thanks again. Last follow up question: In the research I did I saw a lot about unwinding segues rather than the `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` method. In fact, I discovered the `func unwindForSegue(_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue,
towardsViewController subsequentVC: UIViewController)`. Is this perhaps the best practice way of doing this?

Comment: Unwind is good if you want to pop more than one viewcontroller, maybe for you it could be 'info' -> settings -> 'detail' and you want to go from 'detail' to 'info' you could look into unwinding, but if it's just from 'settings' to 'info' dismiss is absolutely fine.